# LoDash _.invokeMap() parameters

Tags: lodash

I one of the rare useful lodash resource i found this exemple

```js
var object = {
           firstName: 'Fredrick',
           lastName: 'Townsend',
           first: function() {
              return this.firstName;
           },
           last: function() {
              return this.lastName;
           }
    };

var methods = _.map(_.functions(object), function(item) {
 return [ _.bindKey(object, item) ];
});

_.invokeMap(methods, 0);
```

I dont understand the second argument (0) of invokeMap

Answer (score 2):

For a start, let's look more simple example:

```js
var array = [
  [function() { console.log('1') }, function() { console.log('2') }],
  [function() { console.log('3') }, function() { console.log('4') }]
];

console.log('_.invokeMap(array, 0)');
_.invokeMap(array, 0);

console.log('_.invokeMap(array, 1)');
_.invokeMap(array, 1);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

And now your code:

```
var methods = _.map(_.functions(object), function(item) {
  return [ _.bindKey(object, item) ]; // <== ! return array
});
```

Function-iterator for `_.map` returns array from one element. Thus, in your example, variable `methods` is the array of two elements, each of them are another array of one element.

[image]

When you pass `0` as second argument here `_.invokeMap(methods, 0);` lodash will iterate from `methods` and invokes the functions which stored in the first element of the array.

Docs for [_.invokeMap](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#invokeMap) method.